# wxPython: Stop threading with wxButton

Tags: python, multithreading

How I can stop threading by clicking a wxButton?

Here is my code:

```
def startMonitor(self,event):       
    selectedInterface = self.interfaces_cblist.GetValue()
    Publisher().sendMessage(("test"),selectedInterface) 
    self.Close()
    selectInterfaceStr = str(selectedInterface) 
    if len(selectedInterface) == 0:
        noSelect_error = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Please select an interface","",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
        noSelect_error.ShowModal()
    else:       
        monitorStarted = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Monitor on %s started"%selectInterfaceStr,"",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
        monitorStarted.ShowModal()
        self.monitorInterface_button.Disable()      
        threading.Thread(target=self.camtableDetection,args=(selectInterfaceStr,)).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.dhcpexhaustion,args=(selectInterfaceStr,)).start()

def camtableDetection(self,getInterface):
        global interface        
        interface = str(getInterface)
        THRESH=(254/4)
        START = 5
        def monitorPackets(p):
            if p.haslayer(IP):
                hwSrc = p.getlayer(Ether).src
                if hwSrc not in hwList:
                    hwList.append(hwSrc)
                delta = datetime.datetime.now() - start
                if((delta.seconds > START) and ((len(hwList)/delta.seconds) > THRESH)):
                    print "[*]- Detected CAM Table Attack."
                    #camAttackDetected = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Cam Attack Detected","",wx.ICON_ERROR)
                    #camAttackDetected.ShowModal()

    hwList = []
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    sniff(iface=interface,prn=monitorPackets)


def dhcpexhaustion(self,getInterface):
    interface = str(getInterface)
    global reqCnt
    global ofrCnt
    reqCnt = 0
    ofrCnt = 0

    def monitorPackets(p):
        if p.haslayer(BOOTP):
            global reqCnt
            global ofrCnt
            opCode = p.getlayer(BOOTP).op
            if opCode == 1:
                reqCnt=reqCnt+1
            elif opCode == 2:
                ofrCnt=ofrCnt+1
            print "[*] - "+str(reqCnt)+" Requests, "+str(ofrCnt)+" Offers."
          sniff(iface=interface,prn=monitorPackets)
```

I am thinking to stop the threading when I click on a button, but have no idea how can it can be done.

There are self.abort techniques, but I'm not sure how to apply it in my code.

Comment: As far as I can tell, both of your thread functions already exit almost immediately, so there's nothing to stop here. If they _were_ running in a continuous loop, the general idea is to have them check something once per loop. What do they check? That depends on what kind of loop it is—a `threading.Condition` around a `quit` flag always works, but if you've already got a reactor or a queue, sticking a pipe in the reactor or using a special value on the queue is usually better.

Comment: Meanwhile, you haven't told us what `sniff` is… If it's a function that you have no control over (e.g., from a C extension module) and it loops forever, then it must have some way to cancel it. Maybe it's having your callback return a special value, maybe it's calling a control function, maybe it's closing the object it's working on… whatever it is, you have to do that. And if it _has_ no way of stopping it… then you'll have to run it in a child process and kill the process, because you can't kill a thread.

Comment: sniff its is a function from scapy.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment:

> If [`sniff` is] a function that you have no control over (e.g., from a C extension module) and it loops forever, then it must have some way to cancel it. Maybe it's having your callback return a special value, maybe it's calling a control function, maybe it's closing the object it's working on… whatever it is, you have to do that.

So, why not read the documentation for `scapy.sniff` to see how to cancel it?

```
Sniff packets
sniff([count=0,] [prn=None,] [store=1,] [offline=None,] [lfilter=None,] + L2ListenSocket args) -> list of packets

  count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity
  store: wether to store sniffed packets or discard them
    prn: function to apply to each packet. If something is returned,
         it is displayed. Ex:
         ex: prn = lambda x: x.summary()
lfilter: python function applied to each packet to determine
         if further action may be done
         ex: lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(Padding)
offline: pcap file to read packets from, instead of sniffing them
timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None)
L2socket: use the provided L2socket
opened_socket: provide an object ready to use .recv() on
stop_filter: python function applied to each packet to determine
             if we have to stop the capture after this packet
             ex: stop_filter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)
```

So, the way to stop it sniffing forever is to pass it a `stop_filter` function, which will return True when you want to stop it. So that function is where you're going to check your `stop` flag. For example:

```
def __init__(self, whatever):
    self.stopflag = False
    self.stoplock = threading.Lock()
    # rest of your init

def stop(self):
    with self.stoplock:
        self.stopflag = True 

def stop_filter(self):
    with self.stoplock:
        return self.stopflag

def dhcpexhaustion(self, getInterface):
    # etc.
    sniff(iface=interface,prn=monitorPackets, stop_filter=self.stop_filter)
```

You're probably going to want to store the two `Thread` objects at start time, so you can `join` them at stop time, rather than just leaking them until your program exits. But otherwise, this should do it.